Could you recommend a book that describes Archimedes' achievements as objectively as possible?
Most of the books I've read that introduce Archimedes' achievements so far are mostly exaggerated, so it's difficult to objectively understand his achievements.
Therefore, I would appreciate it if you could recommend a book that describes Archimedes' achievements as objectively as possible.

Can you list some of the books you read about Archimedes? Are you referring to textbooks?

Archimedes by Dijksterhuis is a classical academic biography with well referenced sources that includes modern translations of Archimedes's works.

Archimedes achievements are hardly possible to exaggerate. So please give some references to the books that do this, to put some substance to your question.

Another well-known book about Archimedes is Archimede, Carocci, 2019, by Lucio Russo, the author of The Forgotten Revolution.
It is in Italian, however, and unfortunately, it has not been translated in English, as far as I know.
But it is surely rigouros and not hagiographic or anecdotal.  The presentation of the book  says:

Several works of Archimedes have come to us, but only few specialists
read them. Some of his results [...] are taught at school, but
without mention of the way Archimedes reached them. So, the thought of the
most important exponent of the Hellenistic school continues  to be
ignored also by classicists and scientists, while its fame with the
public is left to the recollection of some legendary anecdotes.
The critical analysis of the episodes transmitted by the tradition is
here accompanied by the exposition of a substantial part of
Archimedes' results, sufficient to see at work his scientific method.


A nice book that discusses Archimedes and his works is "Archimede – alle radici della scienza moderna" by Pier Daniele Napolitani. It is in Italian; however, the author has made it available for free and it is searchable: you can select the text and use an automatic translator. It might be a bit inconvenient, but don't look a gift horse in the mouth.
